# Transaction failure when deploying an NFT smart contract

Tags: remix, transactions, nft, deploy

I encountered this error while deploying an NFT smart contract, I am a beginner, please help me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The image link is not working. please provide more info to try to find where is the problem.

Comment: Please provide more info, the question is blur.